# SQL Statement to Replace SSM in Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

How would I go about creating a query to replace a social security number from the middle of a text block?

The table is like this:

```
column1     column2
11          text SSN more text
```

SSNs are not all formatted the same either, some are like this xxx-xx-xxxx and some are just a number string xxxxxxxx.

Comment: If you can describe the rules that need to be followed, we can express it in SQL for you.  We need the precise rules you want enforcing though.  (Note: Your second format example is 8 digits, not 9, for example.)

Comment: Also, replace the SSN with what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting for example to redact SSN#'s from your table, you can make use of the [`PATINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) function to find SSN#'s and the [`REPLACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) command to convert them to something that hides the number.  Here is an example (note that this code assumes there will only be one SSN# in a value at once.  If there could be multiple different SSN#'s, only the first one will be found):

```
update
    MyTable
set
    Column2 = replace(Column2, 
        case
            when patindex('% [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %', Column2) <> 0 
                then substring(Column2, patindex('% [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %', Column2) + 1, 11)
            when patindex('% [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %', Column2) <> 0 
                then substring(Column2, patindex('% [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %', Column2) + 1, 9)
            else ''
        end,
        case
            when patindex('% [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %', Column2) <> 0 
                then 'xxx-xx-xxxx'
            when patindex('% [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %', Column2) <> 0 
                then 'xxxxxxxxx'
            else ''
        end)
```

Sample input data:

```
1 | text 123-45-6789 more text
2 | testing 894315466 and blah blah blah
3 | testing no ssn 348933 result
```

Sample Output:

```
1 | text xxx-xx-xxxx more text
2 | testing xxxxxxxxx and blah blah blah
3 | testing no ssn 348933 result
```

Comment: oh man this worked like a champ. thanks for the fast reply. your a god.

Comment: @Ben: Glad to help.  Please make sure you noticed my note above about this code will only match the **first** social security number.  So as long as a field doesn't contain more than one SSN, this should work fine.  If there are possibly multiple, one solution would be to run the code multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the text you have in your field, you could do a replace on all of the hypens, assuming you are trying to normalize the SSNs in to a hypen-less format.  However, if your other text that the SSN is nested in may contain hypens, the below solution won't work.  It'll end up pulling out all of the hypens.

```
UPDATE tableA
SET column2 = REPLACE(column2,'-','');
```

Otherwise, you're dealing with finding the SSN based off 9 numerical digits in a row or 3 digits, followed by a hypen, followed by 2 digits, a hypen, then four.  This would require you to go through the entire field, mark your starting point to start the replacement and doing your parsing work.